# Javascript: passing a URL to google encoding trouble

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, encoding

I'm trying to look at the html data returned from a google reverse image search. The URL I'm passing to google contains some characters that get encoded, notably `?` changes to `%3F`, and google doesn't seem to understand the formatted URL (pic_url below). Is there any way to send the URL so that it does not get formatted? Or is there another way around this issue?

My code looks like:

```
var google_url = "https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=";

var pic_url = "http://img.cpcdn.com/recipes/_o1f2b886e/50x50c/d9e62798f1c807c1891454bed562e4c9.jpg?u=941483&amp;p=1362455199";

var search_url = google_url + pic_url;

$.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + 
                      encodeURIComponent(search_url) + '&callback=?',
                      function(data){
                        $("#targetWrapper").html(data.contents);

                        http_data = data["contents"];
                        console.log(http_data);

            });
```

The error I get back in the console:

```
`The requested URL   <code>/searchbyimage%3Fimage_url=http%253A%252F%252Fimg.cpcdn.com%252Frecipes%252F_o1f2b886e%252F50x50c%252Fd9e62798f1c807c1891454bed562e4c9.jpg%253Fu%253D941483%2526amp%253Bp%253D1362455199</code> 
was not found on this server.  
<ins>That’s all we know.</ins>`
```

But if you just copy and paste `https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=http://img.cpcdn.com/recipes/_o1f2b886e/50x50c/d9e62798f1c807c1891454bed562e4c9.jpg?u=941483&amp;p=1362455199` to the Address Bar it works. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

there is a bug in whateverorigin.org:
https://github.com/ripper234/Whatever-Origin/issues/1

note that the solution proposed doesn't work for me...